How did Johannes Kepler figure out the radius of each planet’s orbit?
I don’t understand how Johannes Kepler got the data to formulate his third law. How was the radius of each planet’s orbit determined?

Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/how-did-kepler-guess-his-third-law-from-data

And same discussion in HSM.SE: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/how-did-kepler-guess-his-third-law-from-data

Copernicus estimated the ratio of each planet. Kepler either used these numbers or recalculated for himself.
For the inner planets (Mercury and Venus), he used the max elongation angles, which is the max angle between the planet and the Sun as observed from Earth. Note this forms a right triangle, so $d= sin(\theta)$, where $d$ is the radius of the inner planet in AU (Earth's orbital radius), and $\theta$ is the max elongation angle.
For the rest of the planets, he measured the time between quadrature and opposition. Knowing the sidereal period of earth and the planet, he estimated the angle swept in that time as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Then $d = 1/ cos(\alpha-\beta)$. From University of Wisconsin astronomy notes here is a figure for clarity:

Copernicus did a pretty good job at estimating planet radii (same source as above):

To me, the more interesting part of Kepler's observations is when he realized ellipses better fit the orbital paths of the planets than the circles used by Copernicus.

Thanks. This helps me understand better. I tried looking up how the radii of planets’ orbits were calculated, but most search results just kept giving me Kepler’s law and not how Kepler (or Copernicus) calculated them.

Note that Kepler only foumd the distances in units of  Earth's distance from the Sun, which wasn't known.  Fifty years later Cassini found the distances in units of length.

@stretch, exactly, and also that’s why the “Astronomical Unit” (AU) is so important. I don’t know the full history, but we didn’t invent AU’s so “we could get” a relative sense of distances, and didn’t name it with such a grandiose name for egotistical reasons. It’s because for a long time we had really precise measurements of the solar system distances but only relative to each other. The size of the orbit of the earth itself was then a convenient yardstick for solar system measurements. When we nailed the size of that orbit in “earthly units”, everything else could be pinned down in turn
